# Rendering bulleted lists from a dataframe in RMarkdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, markdown, knitr

How do I convert this dataframe into

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Z_qdynfqA8f95sNUPq-zPw9NNk5rqT9cV8yTUOwZXrk/edit#gid=0

a nested bullet? Something like this:

Big Bullet 1

- Sample 1

  - Event 1
  - Event 2

    - Detail 1
    - Detail 2

Big Bullet 2

- Sample 1
- Sample 2
- Sample 3

Big Bullet 3

- Sample 1

  - Event 1

    - Detail 1
    - Detail 2
  - Event 2

    - Detail 1
    - Detail 2
  - Event 3

    - Detail 1
    - Detail 2
- Sample 2

  - Event 1
  - Event 2

Thats the idea.

I have a section after a plot that needs a bulleted narrative.
The people I work with dont know R and its easier to collaborate with them (and automate generation at the same time) if the narrative is in a spreadsheet.

I am at a loss with regards to this. My attempts did not work.
PS I am sourcing the external script with the right parameter knit_global()

Comment: You could reference the specific cells with basic R data[1,1] formatting per each bullet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can be solved using `dplyr` perhaps. Given a list

- A

  - AA

    - AA1
    - AA2
  - AB

    - AB1

Which will have the excel/R structure

```
  bullet_1 bullet_2 bullet_3
1        A       AA      AA1
2        A       AA      AA2
3        A       AB      AB1
```

We can `group_by` and `summarise` (using `paste`) iteratively starting at the bottom level, and for each consecutive iteration going up one level in the list by grouping by one less variable. That is, for the first iteration, group_by level 1 (A) and level 2 (AA, AB). This should result in

```
  bullet_1 bullet_2 bullet_3   
1        A       AA      "AA2, AA1"
2        A       AB      AB1
```

Second, grouping by `bullet_1`

```
  bullet_1 bullet_2 
1        A       "AA, AA2, AA1, AB, AB1"
```

And finally

```
  bullet_1  
1        "A, AA, AA2, AA1, AB, AB1"
```

Adding some Markdown list output in between entires and handling for empty cells in excel (NA) this very quick and dirty attempt could be a starting point (replace the path in `read_excel`)

````
```{r, echo=FALSE, results='asis'}

library(dplyr)

frameLoop <- readxl::read_excel("path/to/xlsxfile.xlsx") %>% 

  #add newlines (\n) after each entry to create list structure further down the road. 
  #NA's will be removed later. If NAs are converted to "", will interfere with
  #list structure
  mutate_all(function(x) ifelse(is.na(x), x ,paste0(x, "\n"))) %>% 
  replace(is.na(.), "@NA@")


frameNcol <- ncol(frameLoop)

# Number of indentations (measured in number of spaces) needed to create list
# structure in markdown. Hard coded, the list can be generated for max 3 levels
numSpaces <- c(0, 2, 4)

# Vectors of column names.
# The dynamic is updated each iteration such that columns which are
# removed are not attempted to used in summarise().
bulletNamesDynamic <- bulletNamesStatic <- colnames(frameLoop)

#Counting backwards as we start at the lowest list level
for(i in frameNcol:1){
  
  #These are the columns to group by each iteration
  bulletGroups <- bulletNamesStatic[1:(i-1)]
  
  #The name to give the new variable. In this case it's the same as the one already used
  sumNameVar <- paste0("bullet_", i)
  
  #(tentative) column names to summarise
  sumVars <- rev(paste0("bullet_", frameNcol:(i)))
  
  #However, must be adjusted each iteration due to the fact that 
  #for each iteration, the "final" column is removed
  sumVars <- sumVars[sumVars %in% bulletNamesDynamic]
  
  #At the final iteration, set prefix for the "header", i.e. top level list entry
  if(i == 1){
    prefix <- paste0("\n#### ")  
  } else {
    prefix <- paste0(paste(rep(" ", numSpaces[i-1]), collapse = ""), "- ")
  }
  

   frameLoop <- frameLoop %>% 
    group_by_at(bulletGroups) %>% 
    summarise(!!sym(sumNameVar) := paste0(prefix, !!!syms(sumVars), collapse="")) %>% 
    #Removes NAs. At each iteration, the summarise will not
    #combine a true list entry with NA (by definition). As a consequence, all 
    #entries containing @NA@ will be removed. Might be problematic if true entries  
    #contains "@NA@", e.g. xxxx@NA@. Should be fairly easy to modify
    mutate(!!sym(sumNameVar) := ifelse(grepl("@NA@", !!sym(sumNameVar)), "", !!sym(sumNameVar)))
     
  bulletNamesDynamic <- colnames(frameLoop)

}

paste(frameLoop[[1]], collapse = "") %>% 
  cat()
```
````

Output:

```
#### Big Bullet 1
- Sample 1
  - Event 1
  - Event 2
    - Detail 1
    - Detail 2

#### Big Bullet 2
- Sample 1
- Sample 2
- Sample 3

#### Big Bullet 3
- Sample 1
  - Event 1
    - Detail 1
    - Detail 2
  - Event 2
    - Detail 1
    - Detail 2
  - Event 3
    - Detail 1
    - Detail 2
- Sample 2
  - Event 1
  - Event 2
```